# What is an efficient way to read/write a priority queue to a text file?

Tags: java, data-structures, file-io

I have a priority queue class that I implemented in Java as it being an array of queues. I need a good way (without using Serialization) of recording and storing the contents of the priority queue after each "transaction" or enqueue()/dequeue() of an object from the priority queue. It should serve as a backup in the event that the priority queue needs to be rebuilt by the program from the text file.

Some ideas I had and my problems with each:

- After each "transaction", loop through the queues and write each one to a line in the file using delimiters between objects.
  -- My problem with this is that it would require dequeueing and re-enqueueing all the objects and this seems highly inefficient.
- After each enqueue or dequeue simply write that object or remove that object from the file.
  -- My problem with this is: if this is the approach I should be taking, I am having a hard time coming up with a way to easily find and delete the object after being dequeued.

Any hints/tips/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess I have to ask, since someone is going to anyway, but what's wrong with serialization and deserialization?  Is it a question of performance, and if so, has it actually become a performance problem yet?

Comment: Can you show the code for your priority queue?

Comment: Because wouldn't that mean requiring all classes to be Serialized to have to implement Serializable? Also, data persistance would be an issue because if the classes were changed a bit, Serialization would no longer be able to load outdated records.

Comment: if you can make sure each object will take up a fixed number of lines, why not find it based on line number

Comment: Most queues of this type allow you to iterate over each item in the queue and "peek" it, without actually dequeueing the item.  I'm working on an implementation of a priority queue myself, and that's how it works.

Comment: But if you're persisting this queue after each change, and the queue of any substantial size, you need something with a little more horsepower than just a text file.  Does your application use a database?  Why not store it there?

Answer (score 1):

To loop through a queue you can just iterate over it.  This is non-destructive (but only loosely thread safe)

Writing the contents of the queue to disk every time is likely to be very slow.  For a typical hard drive, a small queue will take about 20 ms to write. i.e. 50 times per second at best. If you use an SSD this will be much faster for a small queue, however you still have to marshal your data even if you don't use Serialisation.

An alternative is to use a JMS server which is designed to support transactions, queues and persistence.  A typical JMS server can handle about 10,000 messages per second. There are a number of good free servers available.

Comment: The iterator does not necessarilly go through the elements in the order of their Priority.

Comment: It doesn't need to to save them in any order.  When you load them into a priority queue it will still behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement your requirements as a log pattern. At the end of your file, append every enqueue and its priority, append every dequeue. If your messaging server crashes, you can replay the log file and you'll end up with the appropriate state.

Obviously, your log file will grow huge over time. To combat this, you'll want to rotate log files every so often. To do this, serialize your queue at a point in time, and then begin logging in a new file. You can even accomplish this without locking the state (freezing queu requests) by simultaneously logging transactions to the old and new logs while a snapshot of the data structure is written to disk. When the snapshot is complete, write a pointer indicating that to disk and you can delete your old log.

Write time and space is n, replays should be rare and are relatively fast.

Answer (score 0):

To find objects easily in second approach...I've couple of suggestions ::

1. You can use your priority function to keep objects sorted in the file.
2. To manage newly added objects at different positions, keep some space between every inserted object in the text file and when an object is inserted, you can use some pointer like behavior to specify the offset or something else which can be easily managed.
3. Use a buffer since writing content evreytime can be very slow.
4. Deletion will be trivial if you use your priority function carefully.
5. Also sorting in small buckets pointed by pointers will be very fast and you can always use a garbage collection type of behavior by compacting all the objects after sometime.

Answer (score 0):

one more suggestions: (to consider if usage one file exactly is not a must):

If your object number is not very large, store each object to a seperate file. Of'course, you will need to make a unique identifier for each object and you can use this identifier to be the file name too. this way, you always add or delete a single file based on the identifier stored in the object. If the objects are of various classes that can't be modified, you simply can store a hashmap that maps identifiers to objects. so before you add an object to a queue, you create an identifier and then add the object and the identifier to the map as a pair and you write a new file names as the identifier and containing the object. I leave what to do on delete and reload as it is nothing more than practice.

personally, I favour what was suggested by Robert Harvey in his comment on the question. consider the use of a database, especially if your project has one already. this will make storing objects and deleting objects easier and faster than locating positions within a file. because even if you find a location of the object in a file, most probably you will need to write the whole file again (only without that object). and that is not different from looping. using a database, you avoid all of this trouble.